# The state of LINQ to NHibernate ActiveRecord

Tags: c#, linq, activerecord, castle-activerecord

Does anyone know if the LINQ to NHibernate ActiveRecord is ready for production?

I'm about to start a project that has some tight modelling deadlines. ActiveRecord looks like a winner as opposed to my previous experiences with LINQ to SQL. LINQ to SQLs db first is nice, but somewhat cumbersome after a while. What makes LINQ to SQL so attractive is LINQ queries.

Can the same LINQ syntax be used in ActiveRecord?

What does the community think of ActiveRecord and LINQ to ActiveRecord for production?

V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time has passed, NHibernate has a LINQ provider since 2.1 and ActiveRecord since 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to ActiveRecord is built on top of LINQ to NHibernate.  This won't be around for a a while, but you can follow progress on [Steve Strong's blog](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/sstrong/Default.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, where can i download the Alpha w/ ActiveRecord and LINQ support? I'd like to play around with it.

Comment: The download is here: http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=73818

Comment: I think that's a different linq to nhibernate provider, as the only one which is in development is the one written by Steve Strong (http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/sstrong/Default.aspx ) and he's not even near 'alpha'. Writing a linq provider is hard, and takes a very long time. I'd be surprised if they could include a full linq provider in v2.1

Comment: @Frans It looks like you're right.  The part making it into 2.1 is the new HQL parser, which will provide the basis for future Linq to NHibernate development.

@CVertex, sorry for the incorrect info.  There is another LINQ to nhibernate alternative out there, but it doesn't work very well apparently.  I'd look at something else for now.  Sorry